# Books about number theory and operator algebras

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, oa.operator-algebras

Does anyone know books that covers both operator algebras and number theory. Actually, a number theory books that has operator algebraic approaches.

Comment: Noncommutative geometry, quantum fields, and motives by Alain Connes and Matilde Marcolli? https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-55/

Comment: @WillSawin Interesting! I didn't know them.